# Catch cx_Oracle executemany() batch insert error "expecting number"

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I have 56 columns and some million rows, which I am inserting in my Oracle Table with the following code:

```
import traceback
import sys
try:
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    df_local = df_scores.astype(object).where(pd.notnull(df_scores), None).copy()
    q_t = '''INSERT INTO Table VALUES ( to_date(  :1, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), '''
    s=''
    for i in range(2, 56):
       s = s + ':'+str(i)+','
    s = s[0:-1] + ' )'
    q_t = q_t + s
    rows = [tuple(x) for x in df_local.values]
    cursor.executemany(q_t, rows)
    conn.commit()
except:    
   print(traceback.print_exc())
   print(sys.exc_info()[2])
```

at some row I am getting the `TypeError: expecting number`error. I would like to know if there is a way I can get the **exact line** of data which is generating the error coz otherwise, it would be very difficult to debug every time I get such error? The used stack trace does not give any further details.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for which rows contain invalid data, you can set `batcherrors=True` during an `executemany()`. This will give you a list of all rows that failed during the insert. You can find an example with a more detailed explanation here: https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html#handling-data-errors.

Comment: unfortunately, still getting the same error: 


rows = [tuple(x) for x in df_local.values]
cursor.executemany(q_t, rows, batcherrors=True)
TypeError: expecting number

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue before.
The source csv had mixed dtypes and no header.

First I read the csv with pandas:

```
pd.read_csv(datafile, error_bad_lines=True, sep='|', encoding='utf-8-sig', dtype=str, header=None,iterator=True, chunksize=200000):
```

Then manually assigned col names via `dataframe.columns`:

```
df.columns = ['ID','Col2',...]
```

Then cast `astype(str)` to all columns:

```
for col in df.columns:
     df[col] = df[col].astype(str).str.encode('ascii','replace').str.decode('ascii')
```

worked for me.